# why is swift app in going in background when control center opens?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

In my swift app i am doing log out when activity will go to background,but it is going in background when control center opens.my code is like:

```
class MyApp:UIViewController{
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification, object: nil)

   func appMovedToBackground() {
        print("App moved to background!")
        self.logout() 
    }
}
```

Is there any way where app will logout when activity runs in background but not when control center opens.

Answer (score 10):

`UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` should not be used for detecting when app goes to background. You should use `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` instead, this will only be called when app actually goes to background and not when opening control center or Notifications from top.

When control center opens your app does become inactive and hence `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notification is fired, This is intended behaviour

Look at apple docs [UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification)

> Posted when the app is no longer active and loses focus.
>
> An app is active when it is receiving events. An active app can be
> said to have focus. It gains focus after being launched, loses focus
> when an overlay window pops up or when the device is locked, and gains
> focus when the device is unlocked.

In your case an overlay window has popped up (Control Center) hence this notification has been fired.

Comment: @sulabhqg : Most welcome :). You can mark the answer as accepted by ticking the green tick if it has helped  you :)